# Generating a downloadable link for a private file uploaded in the Google drive

Tags: python, file, google-drive-api, drive

Is it possible to generate the downloadable link for a private file uploaded in the google drive?

I have tried with the files API and generated the 'webContent Link', but it is accessible only to the owner and the shared users.

(Expecting a public link that can be shared with anyone)

```
def file_info_drive(access_token, file_id):
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token, "content-type": "application/json"}
    response = requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{file_id}', headers=headers)
    response = response.json()

    link = response['webContentLink']
    return link
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to make anyone download the file using `webContentLink`.
- You want to use Drive API v2.
- You want to achieve this using 'request' module with Python.
- You have already been able to upload and download the file using Drive API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- In order to make anyone download the file using `webContentLink`, it is required to share publicly the file.

  - In this modified script, the file is publicly shared with the condition of `{'role': 'reader', 'type': 'anyone', 'withLink': True}`. In this case, the persons who know the URL can download the file.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

```
def file_info_drive(access_token, file_id):
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token, "content-type": "application/json"}

    # Using the following script, the file is shared publicly. By this, anyone can download the file.
    payload = {'role': 'reader', 'type': 'anyone', 'withLink': True}
    requests.post('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{file_id}/permissions', json=payload, headers=headers)

    response = requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{file_id}', headers=headers)
    response = response.json()

    link = response['webContentLink']
    return link
```

#### Note:

- In this case, the POST method is used. So if an error for the scopes occurs, please add `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` to the scope.

#### Reference:

- [Permissions: insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions/insert)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: If we do like this by updating the permissions, will the file in the drive become public?

Comment: @kkr Thank you for replying. At the above modified script, only the file of the file ID is shared publicly. By this, the file can be opened by anyone as the readonly. And also, only users who know the URL can access to it, and in this case, the file cannot be searched by the general search engines.

Comment: Thankyou so much replying and for the detailed descriptions @tanaike

Comment: @kkr Welcome. If my proposed script was not useful for your goal, I apologize.

Comment: No, this is what I expected. Thanks for the help.