# Show Google Drive video on a website using service account

Tags: php, google-drive-api, service-accounts

I'm trying to get a video from my google drive account and publish it on my website.
The idea is to authorize the access to the file using a service account, so the video will be "public" accessible without the user using his google credentials.

Right now for the images I download them and the show it from my server, but due to storage space I would prefer not doing the same for videos

Here's my code:

```
  $client = getGoogleClient();  // Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend
  $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
  switch ($type) {
    case 1: //video
      $startPos=strrpos($url['URL'], "file/d")+7;
      if($startPos>7)
      {
        $endPos=strrpos($url['URL'],"/");
        $url=substr($url['URL'],$startPos,$endPos-$startPos); //its the file id
      }
      // Get files from our request
      $file = $service->files->get($url,array("fields"=>"webContentLink"));
      $customData=$file->webContentLink;
      $customclass="hasVideo";
      break;
    case 3: //img
      if(is_null($img))
      {
        //we have to donwload the file and store it temporaly
        //find img id
        $startPos=strrpos($url['URL'], "file/d")+7;
        if($startPos>7)
        {
          $endPos=strrpos($url['URL'],"/");
          $url=substr($url['URL'],$startPos,$endPos-$startPos);
          $content = $service->files->get($url, array("alt" => "media"));
          // Open file handle for output.
          $filePath="./cachedFiles/".uniqid().".jpg";
          $outHandle = fopen($filePath, "w+");
          // Until we have reached the EOF, read 1024 bytes at a time and write to the output file handle.
          while (!$content->getBody()->eof())
            fwrite($outHandle, $content->getBody()->read(1024));
          // Close output file handle.
          fclose($outHandle);
          $connection->runQuery("UPDATE File_Elemento SET cachedFile='".$filePath."', lastCached='".date('Y-m-d H:m:s')."' WHERE ID=".$ID);
        }
        else
          $type=0;
      }
      else
        $filePath=$img;
      require_once('./ImageCache/ImageCache.php');
      $imagecache = new ImageCache\ImageCache();
      $imagecache->cached_image_directory = dirname(__FILE__) . '/cachedImg';
      $filePath = $imagecache->cache( $filePath );
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  echo '<a onclick="showDetail(this,\''.$customData.'\')" class="grid-item '.($subject ? $subject : "Generico").' '.($customclass!="" ? $customclass : "").'"><div class="card newsCard">'.($type==3 ? '<img class="lazy-load imgPrev" data-src="'.$filePath.'">' : "").'<h3>'.$school.'</h3><h1>'.$name.'</h1>';
  echo '<div class="prev">'.$subject.'</div><span class="goin mainColor">Visualizza</span></div></a>';
```

right now I tried to get the webContentLink and then put the url I get as source for a video tag, but I get a 403 error, so still I didn't authorize the access using the service account

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embedding the `webContentLink` to your website won't make this publicly available. The `webContentLink` is as restricted as the file itself: it can only be accessed by users with which the file has been shared.

So you should do one of these:

- Make this video public (via [Permissions: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create), or through the UI itself) (`role: reader` and `type: anyone`).
- Download it serve it from your server, as with your images.

#### Related:

- [Generating a downloadable link for a private file uploaded in the Google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58318228/generating-a-downloadable-link-for-a-private-file-uploaded-in-the-google-drive)

Comment: thanks! I hoped that in some ways I could authenticate using the service account and then serve it from google directly, I'll go changing the permissions